# Trouble linking Stylesheet in Spring with Thymeleaf

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, stylesheet

So I've been struggling with this for a while and still can't figure it out.

I'm not able to make the external CSS file to work, the browser always gives me a 200 success message but the file never loads.

I've tried many different ways but this is how it looks at the moment:

Linking in the HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Tourverwalter</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/assets/css/myStyle.css}" />
</head>
```

The CSS File:

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
}
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

header{
    vertical-align: top;
}

.container {
    width: 75%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.left {
    width: 40%;
    height:30px;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    margin-left: 60%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

The WebMcvConfig File:

```
package ese4.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
          registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/assets/");

    }

}
```

And the folder Hierarchy: 
[Folder Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nazyh.png)

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes I am using spring Boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot, I would suggest that you change your structure to:

`src/main/resources/static/css`

And then you can remove the overridden `addResourceHandlers` method.  [Spring Boot will use the `static` folder to serve your static content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

Then you would update your link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/myStyle.css}" />
```

Aside: you will also want to include the `href` path to the css so that when you open the file in a browser without loading Spring Boot, you can still see the effect of the CSS.  This is a huge advantage to using Thymeleaf since your UI person doesn't need to know a thing about Java or Spring to see a formatted page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/myStyle.css" th:href="@{/css/myStyle.css}" />
```

Finally, your other method can be simplified to:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer Problem is it still doesn't work...It still gets the css succesful apparently but it doesn't load. And it still says as a warning: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:  Do you happen to have any other idea?

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: Also make sure that the file name is titled exactly myStyle.css

Comment: I finally figured it out.In our homeController.java we had a RequestMapping that it always defaulted to. Commented that out and it worked flawlessly. Comment of my friend: "No idea why I put that there". Thanks for all your help, the static content answer was very useful nevertheless. (Marked your original comment as solution since this will be the standard way to solve such a problem)

Comment: @RobinSteiner oh my God. I was fighting with same issue and your last comment save my life! Thanks man.